# R - evaluating return() in parent environment

Tags: r, function, return, environment

I'd need an "inside" function to return as if it were the parent function.

Example:

```
some_fn <- function() {
  inside_fn <- function() {
    eval.parent(return("I wish"))
  }
  inside_fn()
  return("I wish not")
}

some_fn()
## [1] "I wish not"
```

Using `stop()` with `on.exit()` works...

```
some_fn_2 <- function() {
  on.exit(return("Well, this works"))
  inside_fn <- function() {
    eval.parent(return("I wish"))
    stop()
  }
  inside_fn()
  return("I wish not")
}

some_fn_2()
[1] "Well, this works"
```

... but is sort of hackish and I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this. I know it's not exactly simple; it would imply ignoring part of the call stack, but still, I'd like to know your thoughts, dear community. :)

Comment: I don't think your second example "works":  it will never return `"I wish not"`, whether `inside_fn` asks for a special return or not.

Comment: Good point. But in my present situation, it doesn't really matter. The return value will always be the same... I just want control over the moment it is returned, without having to "check if I can return now" after every operation. The inside function's role is precisely that.

Comment: But you don't have that control.  *Both* return calls are executed.  You can see this if you change `return("I wish not")` to `cat("I wish not")`.

Comment: Okay this seems pretty weird to me. I always thought `stop()` meant "stop"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`callCC` can break out of nested calls:

```
callCC(function(k) {
  inside_fn <- function() {
    k("I wish")
  }
  inside_fn()
  return("I wish not")
})
## [1] "I wish"
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Had to toy a little bit with it, but it worked.