# Put break/next statements inside functions in R

Tags: r, function, loops, iteration, break

I have a complex condition (including side effects) for deciding if go next in a loop, so I would like to extract the logic in a function.

CRAN checks return the following warning:

```
Found the following significant warnings:
     Note: break used in wrong context: no loop is visible 
     Note: next used in wrong context: no loop is visible
```

I have tried doing something like reported in the following minimal reprex, but it returns an error.

```r
# comented code are not needed to reproduce the issue, they are 
# just a sample of some compelxity I would like to extract from the
# cycle using `b`
b <- function() {
  # cat("Doing something complex w/ side effect") 
  # complex_cond <- TRUE
  # if (complex_cond) {
    break
  # } else {
  #   cat("Perform compelx cycle computation")
  # }
}

res <- for (j in letters[1:2]) {
  cat(j)
  for (i in 1:2) {
    cat(i, "\n")
    b()
  }
}
#> a1
#> Error in b(): no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

expected <- for (j in letters[1:2]) {
  cat(j)
  for (i in 1:2) {
    cat(i, "\n")
    break
  }
}
#> a1 
#> b1

res |> identical(expected)
#> Error in identical(res, expected): object 'res' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Independently from the fact that it could be helpful or not, nor if it could be a good practice (surely not! :-) ), do you know if it is possible to do that or, if not, why?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Don't have your function do the `break`/`next` command, just have it evaluate the conditional and return TRUE or FALSE. `if(my_function()) break else next` or something like that. Also `break` is **not** a function, so `break()` is a syntax error,  use `break` without the `()`.

Comment: @r2evans if you want to write up an answer about call stack separation between the loop and the `break` not working, please go ahead!

Comment: Thank you, @GregorThomas. I have fixed the break call (that, in this case, didn't return any syntax error, and it works perfectly well with the expected behavior, despite the fact I agree with you it was a typo and the correct syntax is the current one!...). I have also added some commented code to `b` just as an example of what I mean.

Comment: But again, there's no need for the `break` to be in `b` (and I believe that syntactically you cannot do it). You can have `b` return TRUE of FALSE for break or no break, or you can have it return a meaningful string that you check and dispatch appropriately. I would suggest that *"Perform compelx cycle computation"* might be it's own function, but you don't have to do it that way if you don't want to. You just can't put the `break` **inside** `b()`.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your suggestions and best practices (extracting the function, testing the *complex cycle computation* and everything else: don't manage a loop from inside a function). Still, I am curious about a solution (that I have found!) and why I cannot do that (that I still haven't found yet).

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't break out of a loop from within a function you can return early from an  outer function from within an inner function using `callCC`.  See [R - evaluating return() in parent environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172988/r-evaluating-return-in-parent-environment/54173605#54173605) for an example.

However, here we are just concerned with a conditional `break` for debugging purposes and assuming you control the code I think it would be easier to just define a logical option which turns on or off debugging as shown below.  Below we turn it on or use `options(debug = NULL)` or `options(debug = FALSE)` to turn it off.

```
  options(debug = TRUE)

  for (j in letters[1:2]) {
    cat(j)
    for (i in 1:2) {
      cat(i, "\n")
      if (getOption("debug", FALSE)) break
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit 20220901: the "solution" reported here DOESN'T work!]

Thanks to the [@g-grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) English rephrasing, I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513647/4434088).

I still don't understand *why* I cannot do that directly. Anyway: that's it; there, you can find a solution.

Thank you all!

Comment: `eval.parent(parse(text = "break"))` does not work. If you try running the code in the linked-to post it results in: *Error in eval(expr, p) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level*

Comment: That's right. I won't cancel the answare to maintain evidence of my error. Thank you